# We've graduated. When are the moderator elections?

Tags: discussion, moderators

I've noticed that on most SE sites that finally make a leap into the big leagues (a.k.a. graduation), the first order of business is moderator election. If I recall correctly, I have seen this precede even site design change. PuzzlingSE has graduated and [we have a kickass new site design](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4720/new-site-design). But I don't hear any talk of moderator elections. So when are we going to elect our own moderators?

*PS: I am not interested in running for the election, but getting the chance to choose our own <strike>overlords</strike> moderators is something I would love to do.*

Comment: [This answer on SE meta site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135863/313472) says "we have a set process for determining when a graduating site is ready to support its first election after graduation". You should read that answer for more info.

Comment: You should also look at [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263679/timeline-of-a-stack-exchange-site/263687#263687)

Comment: @manshu: "we have a set process for determining when a graduating site is ready to support its first election after graduation". And the purpose of this question is to get some insight into the process and to figure out how far (near?) the election process really is.

Comment: [Music SE](https://music.stackexchange.com) graduated on 23 Sept. 2015 and then the elections started on 9th Nov 2015. This might give you some idea.

Comment: I stole all of Stack Exchange's spare diamonds. They can't run elections until I give them back. And I don't plan on it. Muahahahaha. _[insert monotonous evil cackle]_

Comment: @Emrakul you're [Doris Payne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doris_Payne), aren't you? The jig is up!