# Puzzling's new favicon is too similar to Workplace's favicon

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, design

[Puzzling](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4720/new-site-design?cb=1) recently got a new site design (congratulations!). As a non-puzzling user though, I have one complaint.

The favicon is very similar to [The Workplace's](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) favicon. This is confusing when looking at the hot network questions list.

A couple current examples (seen from different sites on the network):

[image: Puzzling/Workplace]

---

[image: Puzzling/Workplace 2]

---

The question titles of Puzzling aren't as clear as the Workplace's are, but they aren't outside the realm of possibility for a valid title, especially prior to an edit that further improves the question. I've already clicked on more Puzzling links in the last few days that I ever had and each time I just feel annoyed (and kind of tricked) that I clicked on the link when I was attempting to get to the Workplace. I'm sure the reverse can be true for others.

Can the Puzzling favicon be modified to be more visually distinguishing from Workplace's icon and still keep with their new design?

Comment: I certainly agree with this. I spend most of my time on Workplace, but I frequently enjoy reading the Puzzling posts that show up on HNQ, and often seek them out. I really liked the question mark, which was visually distinct from other sites and also conveyed what the site was about. I know it doesn't make sense to go back to the beta favicon, but I think a more obviously puzzling favicon (question mark, puzzle piece, etc) could work well here.

Comment: I think it makes sense for there to be a post about this on Meta Stack Exchange to see feedback from non-Puzzling users too. The Puzzling community should decide how their icon should look, but that decision may be influenced by hearing how non-Puzzling users are affected by it.

Comment: @trichoplax, I originally posted this on MSE. It was migrated here. It makes sense for Puzzling to have the first say, as it's their icon. I didn't think of that originally when posting, but I agree with the migration. I'd been thinking of this request as a "non-puzzling" user.

Comment: @Andy I don't think non-puzzling users should have any say in it, but I think it would be useful for puzzling users to know what the rest of the network thinks before deciding whether it needs to be addressed.

Comment: This has already been mentioned quite a bit here. I won't claim to speak for the entire userbase, but [this post](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/4727/) pointing it out is at +15/0.

Comment: I definitely just saw a workplace question and thought it was a puzzler.  No fun!  :)

Comment: [A similar question has now been posed on Workplace's Meta](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3711/is-the-puzzling-icon-too-similar-to-ours)

Answer (score 57):

Whilst I quite like the current logo, I think there's plenty of opportunity to keep the spirit of it, and still avoid the overlap with the Workplace logo...

With that in mind I've mocked up a few alternatives:

[image: alternate logos]

The first keeps the "lock icon + impossible geometry" motif of the original design, but switches it to a more classic triangular shape.

The second takes inspiration from the impossible geometry triangle and the original **?** icon of the beta PSE.

The third tries to take the current design, but also shift it back towards a **?** icon.

***Note***: I am by no means a graphic designer, and I'm sure the above could be improved upon, I just wanted to give a few alternatives to help continue the discussion...

Comment: I think the triangular shape is the most interesting of the three

Comment: +1 for the triangular one

Comment: I like the ? the best =D

Comment: Nice alternatives. I also like the triangle. But it seems (to me) not to have an impossible geometry. Only if you connect the lower branches. If not, it appears to be a matter of perspective =)

Comment: @fondor - isn't that what puzzles are about? They appear to be impossible, but really aren't and just need a shift in perspective. ;)

Comment: These alternatives look quite good. They would have made good candidates as logo right from the start.

Answer (score 7):

I've also suffered from this confusion the last few days, despite being certain I wouldn't when I first saw the new icon. Seeing the two icons next to each other in this meta question shows that they look quite similar, but they are easily distinguished when they are adjacent. The problem comes when only one or other appears without the other adjacent to it. Then it throws me.

As a similarly themed but easily distinguishable alternative, I'd recommend an [impossible triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_triangle) instead of an impossible quadrilateral for the puzzling icon.

[image: Impossible triangle from cubes]

Comment: Note that I count myself as a non-puzzling user - I originally tried to post this to Meta Stack Exchange but the question had been migrated here. So this is an outside perspective and a suggestion only.

Comment: You'd want to take care not to make it too similar to the [math.SE] SE icon ([which is also based on a Penrose triangle](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13398/do-those-red-cubes-aligned-circulary-next-to-mathematics-have-any-mathematical-s/13409#13409)), though.

Comment: How about something like a [Kumiki puzzle](https://areablog.s3.amazonaws.com/2016/Apr/Classic_3D_Wooden_Burr_font_b_Puzzle_b_font_IQ_font_b_Brain_b_font_Teaser-1460409759958.jpg)? It's not really impossible geometry though, but at first glance seems like it, and they can take many different unique shapes.

Comment: @WesleySitu those look interesting. I'm not aware of any reason it needs to be impossible - I was just suggesting something similar to the existing icon.

Comment: "They are easily distinguished when adjacent" depends on your screen-resolution and whether or not you're colorblind.

Comment: @SeldomNeedy I agree, but my point was that even for people who can distinguish them when adjacent, they *still* cause confusion when they appear individually.

Comment: @trichoplax Cool. I'll delete my comments on the subject. (Including this one, after there's been time for you to see it.)

Answer (score -2):

### Short answer

We aren't going to change the logo. While the shapes are similar at a glance, the [treatment](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/67818/13855) and [visual identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporate_identity#Visual_identity) are completely different. As the number of site designs increase, it will be impossible to avoid logo collisions.

[image: Sun or Columbia?]

### Long answer

Our designers strive to create designs that reflect the identity of individual sites. If they succeed the site looks like it belongs to the community who uses it. So the primary goal of a logo is to [tie the room together](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_vGK008c_rA) (or whatever actual designers might say). Obviously, they want to avoid logos that look *too* similar, but superficial similarity is not really a concern.

I can think of only two places where the confusion might come up:

1. The Hot Network Question sidebar:

   [image: I will say both sites do appear on the HNQ list fairly often.]
2. People who have both sites open on different tabs:

   [image: I have a ton of tabs.]

I don't think we can possibly address the second problem since site logos would be competing with the entire universe of favicons. The first is something we can control to some degree however. In fact, a couple of years ago I floated the idea of appending the site name to the logo on the HNQ list:

[image: Added site name in HNQ list.]

This would eliminate confusion not just for people who have learned all of our logos, but also for people new to the network. In addition, designers would be free to design logos without stressing about the growing library of site logos.

However, that idea stalled out due to internal disagreements. I'll take the pulse of the team to see if this is something we should revisit.

Comment: "[...] the second problem since site logos would be competing with the entire universe of favicons." - I disagree with this. You don't have to compete against the entire universe. You have to compete against yourself (the Stack Exchange Network). The first place you mention where confusion occurs is the hot **network** questions list. I know that the questions on that list will take me to an SE site. I'm not worried about ending up at some random URL that has a similar favicon. I would like to end up at the SE site that I expect though and the similarity makes that hard

Comment: Normally good UX design is to evaluate designs based on their effectiveness and level of reception with the _users_ -- not just ignoring their input and saying "we know better." I'm sad that it's the official SE response, but glad you were honest enough to write that out here - thank you.

Comment: @Andy: Would the change I suggested (appending a sitename) help with the HNQ problem?

Comment: It depends on how it's done. Some site names are rather long (Science Fiction and Fantasy, Programming Puzzles and Code Golf, 
Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair, etc). Do these all have shortened versions like the "EL&U" in your answer and related to that, does "EL&U" add anything except text I skip over to read the question title, if I don't know what it stands for?

Comment: @Andy: I did the mockup by hand trying a few options. My guess is that we would use something closer to the URL string. So "EL&U" would be "English" and "The Workplace" would be "Workplace". But that would be something for the developers to work out.

Comment: To add to the confusion with your second examples (tabs), this is only made worse if the user has tabs open for the Meta sites of both sites. [Which is which](http://i.imgur.com/ZbSA03I.png)?

Comment: @enderland: I didn't ignore the input here. Rather I disagree with the proposed solution. I suggested an alternate solution that will allow designers to avoid having to worry too much colliding with any of the dozens of other logos. Perhaps there's more to your concerns than have been raised here?

Comment: @Andy: I don't know about you, but I had to pin those tabs to avoid [giving the game away](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zXs26.png).

Comment: @JonEricson I don't know about you, but I don't tend to have many tabs on the front page of meta [so this doesn't give much away](http://i.stack.imgur.com/m4flH.png). And since I had my editor open, comparing two large icons in contrasting colours with differently styled taglines is a fair bit easier than [what we have to deal with](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KZfbY.png).

Comment: @Lilienthal: The second image illustrates my point perfectly. When you shrink a logo and drain away the colors, it's inevitable that some pair of logos will look pretty similar as the number of site designs increase. The Columbia and Sun logos are _much closer_ in my eye to the Puzzling and Workspace logos in the first image. My decision _might be_ stupid, but the responses so far have only made me wonder if there's something more going on than represented in the question. Are you concerned Puzzling is co-opting The Workplace's brand identity?

Comment: @JonEricson My main concern is the apparent lack of sanity checks in the design phase to prevent what happened here. As far as I can tell beta users have no way of contributing to the design process or do any kind of evaluation and are stuck with the design they get. I don't disagree with that choice as I can imagine the endless debate that would ensue, but I would hope that the design is at least reviewed by a group of users with site experience and goes through an internal approval process. [...]

Comment: I think anyone who routinely browses the site would be familiar with HNQ and hence immediately see the similarities between the new icon and that of the Workplace, which is featured there often. The logo example I created is a poor one as it lost too much fidelity. There are indeed [a lot of logos](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=c8b4759a52f7) at this point and a 16x16 canvas certainly imposes some design challenges, but let's not pretend like we can only have 150 distinct designs when the internet has [thousands](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mSwQP.jpg)

Comment: @Lilienthal: You are assuming that superficially similar logos are a serious problem. I agree they are becoming increasingly less useful for people wanting to identify sites at a glance. But I strongly disagree that designers should worry about shape duplication. I often confuse RPG with Graphic Design and Sharepoint with Skeptics, but that's the cost of having many designs. (As an aside, can you identify which sites belong to the various penguins in your second image?)

Comment: I like the name. I have seen new/uncommon sites pop up in that list and wondered, "where on earth is THAT on-topic?" - names could make lesser-known sites more visible.

Comment: @JonEricson Well I wouldn't call it a serious problem, just an easily preventable one. The problem with this instance is that the shape is near-identical and they use too many pastel colours that aren't distinct or obvious enough. RPG and Graphic Design share a similar shape but only use a single solid colour which is a good way to tell them apart. That doesn't really work for these, which is the main problem I have with the design. If we use complex designs in 16x16 we should make an extra effort to ensure they are visually distinct from any others.

Comment: As for the penguin icons: no I can't identify the sites because I have no clue which sites are involved, it's a random example. If I browsed two Linux sites which have a penguin as a favicon one would be "the fat penguin" and the other the "baby penguin". There's a black penguin, a big-eyed penguin and so on. The problem is that Puzzling now has the slightly greenish-red pastel square while Workplace has the slightly blueish-red pastel square.

Comment: What I take issue with is the effort you seem to go to in order to pretend like there isn't a problem. I can understand a decision to not change the design now that it's here. I don't have to like that decision but I acknowledge that it isn't a priority for SE. But if we can't change this now, can we at least try to avoid it in the future as more sites graduate?

Comment: The Sun and Columbia logos are a horrible example and not at all relevant here. Sun and Columbia are two completely independent companies that do business in very different industries. You are almost never going to see the two logos in the same context. The Puzzling and Workplace icons are both within and controlled by the SE Network and very often appear next to each other. Simply saying that "it will be impossible to avoid logo collisions" is not a good answer, as it doesn't appear that you have even tried to prevent it.

Comment: @DavidK: If you don't like that example (which I mostly picked because they use filled in versions of the logos in question), who about [two basketball teams in the same city](http://www.logodesignlove.com/images/similar/la-lakers-la-clippers-logos.jpg)? What do you think about my proposal that we add site names to the logo on the HNQ list?

Comment: @JonEricson I agree that's a much better example, though I think the newer team could have made some different design decisions. I do like adding the names to the HNQ list and think that would help a lot. I think a similar solution would then need to be applied anywhere sites are identified only by their logo. The only other place I can think of is the [SE Hot Questions page](https://stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @JonEricson I think what bothers me (and probably others) most is that this design decision affects us at the Workplace, but we had no say in the matter. In the real world you obviously can't expect this, but we are a closed community with common oversight. We shouldn't all be involved in site-specific decisions, but I would expect those who approve such changes to consider how it may affect others in the greater SE community. I don't feel like that happened here.

Comment: This discussion reminds me of the days we used to waste designing toolbar icons for Windows MDI apps. Took way too long to realize that very few tiny pictures are actually worth 1000 words... Text is better, 100% behind the alternate idea here.

Comment: The names are overkill. People might not instantly grasp what the favicons mean, but they don't really have to- you can usually infer most of the context from the name of the question itself (and if you can't, it's probably not a Stack Exchange site you would be interested in).

Comment: @LeslieP. I disagree that you can usually infer a site's topic based on the title, particularly for Puzzling. Some examples from their [hot list](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/?tab=hot) - "My odd music teacher", "Two fuses burn for 45 minutes", "In which US city would you find the following?", "One Ring to rule them all"

Comment: @LeslieP. Time to craft a mystery puzzle "Who murdered my boss and why?" :-)

Comment: @DavidK: Puzzling is one of the few exceptions to the general rule (which is why this entire discussion is so important).

Comment: I like the idea of adding site names. It would also add a bit of context to some of the "crazy" sounding Gaming titles like "How can I tell if a corpse is safe to eat?" and "Is it dangerous to go extreme pig riding in a thunderstorm?"

Comment: @Blorgbeard: Gaming was, in fact, the original impetus for this idea. Also a possibility for clarifying what questions are actually about: [append the primary tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113664/1438). I'm going to talk to a designer this week to see if we can get a general solution to the tiny-logos-and-crappy-titles-make-it-hard-to-identify-the-site problem.