# Puzzling chatroom logo-text misalignment

Tags: bug, design, chat

Alconja's answer [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4637/30903) in the [Puzzling Design Pitch](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4630/puzzling-design-pitch-congratulations-youre-graduating) post mentions realignment of the Puzzling logo at the top of the site, moving it as shown in the below gif (credits to them):

[image: Realignment]

This is what it looks like now (it is implemented):

[image: Nice alignment]

Now, move over to any Puzzling chatroom, say, [The Sphinx's Lair](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair). Look at the logo in the bottom-right (only for non-mobile users, unfortunately):

[image: Bad alignment]

Or, you could look at the one-boxed post [`puzzling.stackexchange.com`](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41222264#41222264), anywhere on the chat network:

[image: Bad alignment again]

Whoops! The logo and the text are jammed up next to each other and have different centre lines, as Alconja mentioned in their post.

It may be my OCD firing, but:

> ## Can we please bring the chatroom logo and text into alignment* with the main site?

<sup>* Pun intended</sup>